# How to deploy an ASP.Net Web Forms on Apache with mono mod

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, mod-mono

I made an ASP.Net Web Forms application and it's working in debug mode in Visual Studio 2012. But when I uploaded the application folder into my Apache with mod_mono I got an Error that indicates I should do this in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My question now is, how should I set up my application from Debug to Release? When I clicked on create application it just gave me a short message in the console. When I use the deploy application option I got a menu with some serversettings that I don't understand and that I don't know.

**edit**

now i got this Error Message:

> Parser Error
>
> Description: Error parsing a resource required to service this
>   request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.
>
> Parser Error Message: The file '~/Site1.Master' does not exist
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
>   MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm6" %>
>   Line 2:  Line 3:

but i there is the Site1.Master in this folder.

Comment: To setup your application to build in Release mode, you can either select the "Release" mode on the toolmenu or right click your application then select Properties. Then click the Build menu on the right then select "Release" on the Configuration dropdown.

Comment: I will try this, thank you. I also found this Tutorial I hope it will work somehow: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9738/Introduction-to-Mono-ASP-NET-with-XSP-and-Apache)

Answer (score 1):

File names are case-sensitive in Linux. Make sure `Site1.Master` has exactly the same name, not `site1.master`, `site1.Master` etc.

It is covered in [Mono portability guidelines](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Portability#Case_sensitivity) and [ASP.NET FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_ASP.NET#Portability).

Comment: Tank you for your answer, the name is exactly like its in the header of the aspx file is. when i change '~/Site1.Master' to './Site1.Master' i get a new Error Message: `Parser Error Message: Cannot find type WebApplication1.WebForm6

Source Error:

Line 1: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="./Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm6" %>
Line 2: 
Line 3: <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">`

Comment: Make sure every file name also conforms to it's declaration, for example `Default.aspx.cs`, `Default.aspx`

Comment: i found this on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908438/hosting-an-asp-net-project-on-shared-hosting-parser-error-message-could-not-l) i will try it

Comment: How is it going? Have you found the solution to your problem?